# How do I create a view that stays onscreen while I switch between tabs?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with 5 different items, each representing different views. These views represent a dialpad, contacts, call history, etc. Selecting a different tab switches to a different view controller and displays a different view, as is standard.

However, I'd like to display a persistent view that does not switch when different selections are made on the tab bar. How can I display such a view that remains onscreen at all times?

Comment: What are you write the code for showing balance

Comment: Can you explain more with some code or screen shot??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crete a shared view controller. And add the view on window whenever its necessary, and bring that view to front.